# How to change the link of CC in Centos

Tags: compiling, path, gcc

I am writing to ask about how to choose the version of gcc during compiling. In my machine, I believe there are several version of gcc installed. Because the command 'gcc -v' returns 'gcc version 6.4.0 (GCC)', while command 'cc' returns 'gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC)'. I know the 'cc' is actually linked to the gcc compiler. And in the makefile, 'CC ?= gcc' should be the command to link cc to gcc.

Thus, is that means the gcc 4.4.7 is always be used when I compiling? Please, how should I change the cc or the makefile to make it link to the newer gcc version? btw, I don't have the permission to use 'sudo' command.

edit:
Thanks for your replying. The output of type -a cc is 
'cc is /usr/bin/cc' 
and another output is 
'gcc is /util/bin/gcc
 gcc is /usr/bin/gcc'
The upper path is the gcc 6.4 and the lower one is older version.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `type -a cc` and `type -a gcc`.

Answer (score 1):

`CC` in your `makefile` is just the variable. You can specify any compiler or executable in your system.

Find direct path of your "newer" gcc and put it on `CC={Path}`
and compiling should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
CC ?= gcc
```

in the Makefile means "if the variable `CC` isn't already set, set it to `gcc`".

Later in the Makefile, the compiler listed in the `CC` variable will be used to compile C language files (`CC` is a standard variable for the C compiler).

If `gcc` is the compiler you want to use, you don't have to change anything.

If you want to use another compiler, such as `clang` or `gcc-7` or something else completely, you do *not* have to change the Makefile.  Instead, just say

```
make CC=clang
```

on the command line (where `clang` may be just the compiler executable name, or its complete path if it's not available in your own `$PATH`).

To use `ccache` (a ["compiler cache"](https://ccache.samba.org/)) with e.g. `clang`,

```
make CC='ccache clang'
```

Since the Makefile tests whether the `CC` variable is set before setting it to `gcc`, the above mentioned way is the best way to invoke `make` with a different compiler.  If it had set the value of `CC` unconditionally, then you would have had to edit the Makefile.